# Error while hosting .NET core 2.0.8 target application to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

While publishing my application on IIS I am facing the issue below: -

.Net core target application : - 2.0.8
.net core hosting bundle is 2.1.0

```
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.get_Signature()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher..ctor(ConstructorInfo constructor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Comment: This assembly does not match what was requested and therefore you get this error.Try to update the required installation package：Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions -Version xxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to install the latest hosting package for release 2.x ?

Try to remove the package `Microsoft Extension.Configuration.Abstractions` from your package reference and then readd it using newest version.

Then delete the nuget cache.